# eclipse project has to run twice to compile updates

Tags: java, eclipse

Recently my eclipse (version 3.8.1) started to behave strange. Assume I'm running a particular java project and I have hit the run button to run the project and now if I do some modifications to the code and rerun it, I will get output for the previously executed code. The new updated code is executed when I'm running my project for the second time.

Restarting eclipse won't resolve this. <strike>This won't happen if I'm debugging the code.</strike>

**EDIT**: for debugging I found that at the first run it ignores any debugging points and just run the code (the previous version). So even for debugging I have to run debug twice if I do a modification to the code.

Comment: no it's not a web applications. Just a simple java project. -BIll!

Comment: This behavior sounds like a) Build Automatically is not turned on, b) wherever you're building to is not getting deleted prior to running your code (sometimes due to persistent file locks), or c) you have multiple instances of your application running at the same time.

Comment: (a) Project -> Build Automatically is turned on.  (c) I have checked that I don't have multiple instances are running at the same time. (b) How do I check if this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it will help, but for me it worked:
Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching: in field "General Options" check the box in the string "Build (if required) before launching".
When i had a same problem, that box was unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was with the order of builds.

Go to project 'Properties' > 'Builders'.
Make sure that Java Builder is on the top.